# Is the REB translation of Ex 11:1, comparing to a rejected bride, supported in the original language?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, bride

Exodus 11:1b in the Revised English Bible (REB) reads:

> When he finally lets you go, he will drive you out forcibly as a man might dismiss a rejected bride.

The simile seems most unusual. Was it in the original language?

Comment: Admittedly, my Hebrew is rusty but, as I read Exo. 11:1, the difference in how to read the word is not in its voweling but its spelling; e.g., KaLaH vs. KaLLaH. More specifically: both the unpointed Masoretic Text (MT) and the Westminster Leningrad Codex (WLC) show כלה (KLH) to be read as "completely". If the Hebrew word for "bride" was in that verse, then the spelling of that word would be כּלּה (note dagesh Lamed or L, transliterated as KLLH).

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** There is no basis for "bride" in the original Hebrew.

The Hebrew text of Exodus 11:1b is:

> כְּשַׁ֨לְּח֔וֹ כָּלָ֕ה גָּרֵ֛שׁ יְגָרֵ֥שׁ אֶתְכֶ֖ם מִזֶּֽה׃ ([Westminster Leningrad Codex](http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Ex11:1-11:1))

The word which is translated by REB as "bride" is the word "כָּלָה".

The word "כָּלָה" (vocalized here with a *qamatz* below the *kaph* and no *dagesh* in the *lamedh*) means completion, especially complete destruction or annihilation.

REB confused "כָּלָה" with "כַּלָּה" (with a *pataḥ* below the *kaph* and a *dagesh* in the *lamedh*), which does, in fact, mean "bride", but has no relationship to Exodus 11:1.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for the explanation. I think they didn’t really “confuse” the issue so much as they thought it appropriate to emend the MT vocalization. The original proposal appears to be in French (beyond me), but see [Morgenstern, J, The Despoiling of the Egyptians. JBL 1949](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3261551?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) for summary and development.